# Regular expression problem with back slashes

Tags: regex, autoit

I'm having trouble with what seems like a simple regex capture.  I'm using AutoIt's stringRegExp() function.

The source string is:

```
1 U:\some text here\more text over here\06-17-2011\Folder 2\161804\abc9831\xyz10007569.JPG
```

I'm trying to capture "abc9831" and "161804".  The "abc" part can be "abc", "def", or "ghi", followed by a string of digits.  The "161804" can be replaced with any string of text.  Everything is case insensitive.  I'm currently using the following regex pattern:

```
(?i)\\\\.+\\\\((abc\d+)|(def\d+)|(ghi\d+))
```

But it's only capturing the "abc9831" part.  How do I pick up the text string preceding it?

Comment: After having asked 9 question we can expect you to know about the basics of formatting. Please format your question to improve readability.

Comment: @darkdust, when i used double slashes in my original post they appeared as single slashes in the preview window below.  that's why I used 4 slashes.  is that what you mean?

Comment: No, I mean indenting the regex so it's displayed like code. Amber did it for your. Please try to format it better next time, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the regex below is used in AutoIt's `StringRegExp()` function (using the flag "1" to return an array of matches), it returns `161804\abc9831`. Is this what you're wanting to return?

```
.*\\([^\\]+\\[a-z]{3}\d+)\\.*
```

Here's an example you can run yourself:

```
#include <Array.au3>

$string = 'U:\some text here\more text over here\06-17-2011\Folder 2\161804\abc9831\xyz10007569.JPG'

$capture = StringRegExp($string,'.*\\([^\\]+\\[a-z]{3}\d+)\\.*',1)

_ArrayDisplay($capture)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?i)\\\\(.+\\\\(abc\d+)|(def\d+)|(ghi\d+))
```

should do the trick if you want it all in one string (with a `\` in between).

If you want two separate captures:

```
(?i)\\\\(.+)\\\\((abc\d+)|(def\d+)|(ghi\d+))
```

Comment: no, that's still just picking up abc9831.  maybe it's an autoit-specific regex issue?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: New version...

The raw regex is `\b(\d+)\\((?:abc|def|ghi)\d+)`.  The escaped string is `\\b(\\d+)\\\\((?:abc|def|ghi)\\d+)`

Comment: @sigil, I added the escaped form.  Does this meet your needs?

Comment: no, that didn't capture anything from the string.  looks like your pattern is trying to catch "abc9831" and then text after it; I'm trying to get "abc9831" and the text before it.  In any case, the pattern didn't return any matches.

Comment: @sigil.  I've added a new one.  It uses a word boundary `\b` to detect the begining of the 161804, but you may be able to use a positive lookbehind instead: `(?<=/)`.